# Puppeteer - get input element by xpath and then click and type

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am trying to login and for this I've made the function:

```
async function login(page, usernameXPATH, passwordXPATH, username, password)
{
  const usernameElement = await page.$x(usernameXPATH);
  await usernameElement[0].click({clickCount: 3});
  await page.type(usernameElement[0], username);

  const passwordElement = await page.$x(passwordXPATH);
  await passwordElement[0].click({clickCount: 3});
  await page.type(passwordElement[0], password);

  await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
}
```

But this generates an error

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
        --> starting at object with constructor 'BrowserContext'
        |     property '_browser' -> object with constructor 'Browser'
        --- property '_defaultContext' closes the circle Are you passing a nested JSHandle?
        at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)

      at Connection._rawSend (node_modules/puppeteer/src/common/Connection.ts:100:37)
      at CDPSession.send (node_modules/puppeteer/src/common/Connection.ts:259:33)
      at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (node_modules/puppeteer/src/common/ExecutionContext.ts:252:44)
      at ExecutionContext.evaluateHandle (node_modules/puppeteer/src/common/ExecutionContext.ts:191:17)
      at ElementHandle.evaluateHandle (node_modules/puppeteer/src/common/JSHandle.ts:183:42)
      at Object.internalHandler.queryOne (node_modules/puppeteer/src/common/QueryHandler.ts:68:38)
      at ElementHandle.$ (node_modules/puppeteer/src/common/JSHandle.ts:778:25)
      at DOMWorld.$ (node_modules/puppeteer/src/common/DOMWorld.ts:171:34)
```

If I remove `[0]` and use just `usernameElement.click()` then I get an error that `click()` is not a function.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The message object passed to https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/4152383c2ce65d5b57fe525cda2f2a7e1c94f401/src/common/Connection.ts#L100 seems to have a circular reference inside. Maybe try putting a breakpoint to see the passed value.

Comment: It is a simple HTML element... `className: 'HTMLInputElement'`

Answer (score 1):

[`Page.type`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&show=api-pagetypeselector-text-options) accepts a selector as its first argument, not an element (matched by an XPath). Rather use [`elementHandle.type`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&show=api-elementhandletypetext-options), e.g.:

```js
async function login(page, usernameXPATH, passwordXPATH, username, password)
{
  const usernameElement = await page.$x(usernameXPATH);
  await usernameElement[0].click({clickCount: 3});
  await usernameElement[0].type(username);

  const passwordElement = await page.$x(passwordXPATH);
  await passwordElement[0].click({clickCount: 3});
  await passwordElement[0].type(password);

  await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
}
```